# How to use chrome.experimental.webRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome extension, and need to use the chrome.experimental.webRequest API. I have a simple background.html, which simple includes a script file. Currently, the script looks like this:

```
function listenBeforeRequest(args) {
  console.log(args);
};

chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(listenBeforeRequest);
```

I have set a breakpoint on the addListener line, and it gets executed when the extension is loaded, and I get no errors. However, the `listenBeforeRequest` method never gets hit. My expectation would be that the function was called before each request.

How can I make this work ?

I am using Google Chrome 16 on Windows. I have set the experimental API flag in the browser under `chrome://flags`.

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "...",
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["background","webRequest","experimental", "*://*"]
}
```

**Note**, I also tried `chrome.webRequest` but that's undefined - even though this page claims it has been added as a stable API: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html

What am I missing ? What do I need to do to get `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` event to work ?

Comment: Notice the `trunk` in http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html. That refers to the Chrome dev channel where `webRequest` is a stable API. In the stable version of Chrome (without `trunk` in the url) the API is stil experimental http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html

Comment: @abraham, do you happen to know when the webRequest API will make it into the stable version of Chrome (as a supported API ?)

Comment: I don't know for sure but the 6 week release cycle should bring it within the next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permission [match pattern](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) lacks a path.  Amend it to something like `*://*/*` or, alternatively, use the special pattern `<all_urls>`.

Comment: Actually, you were half correct. I had the match pattern wrong, but I also forgot the second parameter to addListener, which I thought were optional. The correct call is addListener(listenBeforeRequest, { urls: ["http:*://*/*"] }